# Change websocket scope (from application to session/view)

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

I created a basic web socket with a tutorial.

Here is a configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
         registry.addEndpoint("/chat");
         registry.addEndpoint("/chat").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

And here is the message handling controller:

```
@MessageMapping("/chat")
@SendTo("/topic/messages")
public OutputMessage send(Message message) throws Exception {
    return new OutputMessage("Hello World!");
}
```

Everything works, but from my investigation, it looks like the WebSockets by default has an application scope (by connecting to the channel I can see all calls, from all users).

What I want to do is to be able to see only calls from the current user session or current view only.
Any ideas on how to apply these configurations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this puzzle, so I'm sharing with you my findings.

First, I found information that a simple in-memory message broker can not handle this:

```
    /*
     * This enables a simple (in-memory) message broker for our application.
     * The `/topic` designates that any destination prefixed with `/topic`
     * will be routed back to the client.
     * It's important to keep in mind, this will not work with more than one
     * application instance, and it does not support all of the features a
     * full message broker like RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ, etc... provide.
     */
```

But this was misleading, as it can be easily achieved by `@SendToUser` annotation.
Also, the important thing that now on the client-side, you need to add an additional prefix `/user/` while subscribing to the channel, so the solution would be:

1. On the server-side: change `@SendTo("/topic/messages")` into `@SendToUser("/topic/messages")`.
2. On the client-side: `/topic/messages` into the `/user/topic/messages`.